# Reformat multi-index columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multi-index columns df as below

```
  stock1        stock2        stock3       
   price volume  price volume  price volume
0      1      2      3      4      5      6
1      2      3      4      5      6      7
```

I want to reformat it in such a way that it looks like below

df

```
   price                      volume           
   stock1 stock2 stock3 stock1 stock2 stock3
0      1      3      5      2      4      6
1      2      4      6      3      5      7
```

How can I achieve it in pandas.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.swaplevel(1, 0, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```